# There is dirt in my sensor

Tags: nikon

I just cleaned my sensor with a cloth and when i test the dirt, I saw different dark spots on the image. What should i do? I've tried blowing with blower, but it didn't help.

Comment: cloth? What liquid did you use?

Comment: Oh dear. You should have used one of the recommended sensor cleaning kits for your camera. I just take my gear in for servicing and get it cleaned that way, which is what I recommend for you because you might need to find out if you damaged anything.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be dirt. You can have what is called a dead pixel on your sensor. Take a picture and load it onto your computer and zoom in all the way. If it's pure black and square, it's a dead pixel.

Also there are very particular ways to clean your sensor and using a regular cloth is not one of those ways. Check this video out for more info on how to correctly clean your image sensor: https://youtu.be/MufEqSA0PJI